# implement foreach asp.net mv4 into javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Gives error:

```
if(v.Name == name) // cannot find the variable name
```

Here's the code:

```
function AddUser(chatHub, id, name) {

    var userId = $('#hdId').val();
    var code = "";

    if (userId == id) {
        code = $('<div class="loginUser">' + name + "</div>");
    } else {

        @foreach(UserProfileModel v in ViewBag.Friends) {
            if (v.Name == name) { //error
                code = $('<a id="' + id + '" class="user" >' + name + '<a>');
            }
        }
        $(code).dblclick(function () {

            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            if (userId != id) OpenPrivateChatWindow(chatHub, id, name);
        });
    }
    $("#divusers").append(code);
}
```

Comment: What's your question regarding this code?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
    @foreach(UserProfileModel v in ViewBag.Friends) {
        <text>
        if ('@v.Name' == name) { 
            code = $('<a id="' + id + '" class="user" >' + name + '<a>');
        }
        </text>
    }
```

This way you tell Razor in an explicit way that the code is a part of the content rather than the server-side template.

The `'@v.Name'` is to somehow get the actual value of the server-side variable so that it can be rendered to the client-side script.

I am not sure however if this is your intention.

Comment: [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `code = $('<a id="' + id + '" class="user" >' + '@v.Name' + '<a>');                             // why does it appear only one name of my database but many times   i tried doing the foreach in simple html in the view and it appear all my friends names of database                                                                      How can i resolve code = $('<a id="' + id + '" class="user" >' + '@v.Name' + '<a>'); to appear all the names and not only one but many times `